# how to save an image from UWP into MYsql using php

Tags: c#, php, mysql, win-universal-app

It's my first time developing on UWP and I can't add an image into Mysql database using PHP and I must add its' path in the database.

I can't use sqlite or any other database as my collegues started  already using Mysql. 
Can anyone please help me or give an example 
I wouLd really appreciate your help (i'm stuck here )

So, here is my UWP code that I used to upload the chosen image from my gallery

```
private Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
        private CancellationTokenSource cts;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void buttonUpload_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FileOpenPicker open = new FileOpenPicker();
        open.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
        open.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;

        // Filter to include a sample subset of file types
        open.FileTypeFilter.Clear();
        open.FileTypeFilter.Add(".bmp");
        open.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
        open.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
        open.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");

        // Open a stream for the selected file
        StorageFile file = await open.PickSingleFileAsync();

        // Ensure a file was selected
        if (file != null)
        {
            // Ensure the stream is disposed once the image is loaded
            using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
            {
                BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(fileStream);
                fileStream.AsStream().CopyTo(stream);
                img.Source = bitmapImage;
            }
        }
    }

    private async void submit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {         
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost/mydatabase/add.php");
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpStreamContent streamContent = new HttpStreamContent(stream.AsInputStream());
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri);
        request.Content = streamContent;
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(uri, streamContent).AsTask(cts.Token);

        `
```

and here is the php i'm using

```
 <?php
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
  $UserName = $_POST['UserName'];
 $UserImage = $_POST['UserImage'];
 require_once('conn.php');
 $sql ="SELECT  UserId FROM user";
 $res = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
 $UserId =0 ;
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){     
 $UserId = $row['UserId'];
 $UserId = $UserId+1;
 }
 $path = "UserImage/$UserId.png";
 $actualpath = "http://localhost/mydatabase/$path";
 $sql = "INSERT INTO user (UserId,UserName,UserImage) VALUES ('$UserId','$UserName','$actualpath')";
 if(mysqli_query($connect,$sql)){
 file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($UserImage));
 echo "Successfully Uploaded";
 } 
 mysqli_close($connect);
 }else{
 echo "Error";
 }
 ?>
```

And all what i get is empty images in the folder I created ... apparently I have a problem after uploading the image from the UWP, but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: Please add details to narrow down the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs. Is your problem in UWP client or in PHP server? It would be better if you can include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Comment: yes ,,, please check my edited question .. thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with PHP, so I don't know whether your PHP code is right. But it seems you are posting `UserName` and `UserImage` as form data. In this case, you can use [`HttpMultipartFormDataContent` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn279596) to send text and file mixed content. You'd better make sure your PHP server is working well first and then deal with the UWP client.

Comment: yes it working just fine , i used the same file in Android but the only difference is that my output there is string : thats why i'm using " file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($UserImage));
".. but now in UWP i don't know what to do as my output is an image stream ...

Comment: The UWP code you posted only post an image stream to server. Using this code you won't get `UserName` or `UserImage` in server, you need to change your PHP code to receive the stream. And if you want to get `UserName` and `UserImage` as form data in server, you need change your UWP code and use `HttpMultipartFormDataContent` class as I've mentioned. However, after [a quick search](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp), PHP seems to use `$_FILES` to get the posted file. So I suggest you create a html page to test your server first and then write UWP code according to your server.

Comment: Thanks again ... can you please give an example of the UWP code and the php file as i tried this before but unfortunately it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Read the file using PHP and insert that into the database.
Keep in mind, the bigger the image the longer the string.

```
$data = file_get_contents('/pics/item.png');

return $data;
```

This would return the data(from the picture)

Comment: thanks , can you please give me an example .. i really appreciate your help

Comment: eg. use file_get_contents('URL') or path to the file, this will return the data that u can input into mysql. it is very very large tho

Comment: thanks , i thought you already have or posted some project or full example that i can understand with the whole process .. i really don't know where to start from ..thanks again